# Lion on LDAP Linux domain

Tags: macos, mac, unix, authentication, ldap

I need to put a desktop Mac OS X Lion in the domain of a corporate network - Linux LDAP.

The Mac is already picking up the IP and the DNS name released. But I can not log into the corporate network.

#### opendirectoryd.log.9

```
2012-08-06 14:26:07.780 BRT - opendirectoryd (build 172.10) launched...
2012-08-06 14:26:07.780 BRT - Logging level limit changed to 'error'
2012-08-06 14:26:07.788 BRT - Initialize trigger support
2012-08-06 14:26:07.789 BRT - Registered node with name '/Active Directory' as hidden
2012-08-06 14:26:07.790 BRT - Registered node with name '/Configure' as hidden
2012-08-06 14:26:07.790 BRT - Discovered configuration for node name '/Contacts' at path '/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations//Contacts.plist'
2012-08-06 14:26:07.790 BRT - Registered node with name '/Contacts'
2012-08-06 14:26:07.791 BRT - Registered node with name '/LDAPv3' as hidden
2012-08-06 14:26:07.793 BRT - Registered node with name '/Local' as hidden
2012-08-06 14:26:07.794 BRT - Registered node with name '/NIS' as hidden
2012-08-06 14:26:07.794 BRT - Discovered configuration for node name '/Search' at path '/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations//Search.plist'
2012-08-06 14:26:07.794 BRT - Registered node with name '/Search'
2012-08-06 14:26:08.485 BRT - Discovered configuration for node name '/LDAPv3/hpp.br' at path '/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/LDAPv3/hpp.br.plist'
2012-08-06 14:26:08.485 BRT - Registered subnode with name '/LDAPv3/hpp.br'
2012-08-06 14:26:08.486 BRT - Loaded bundle at path '/System/Library/OpenDirectory/Modules/legacy.bundle'
2012-08-06 14:26:08.488 BRT - Loaded bundle at path '/System/Library/OpenDirectory/Modules/search.bundle'
2012-08-06 14:26:09.491 BRT - '/Search' has registered, loading additional services
2012-08-06 14:26:09.491 BRT - Initialize augmentation support
2012-08-06 14:26:09.494 BRT - Loaded bundle at path '/System/Library/OpenDirectory/Modules/SystemCache.bundle'
2012-08-06 14:26:09.498 BRT - Successfully registered for Kernel identity service requests
2012-08-06 14:26:09.503 BRT - Loaded bundle at path '/System/Library/OpenDirectory/Modules/PlistFile.bundle'
2012-08-06 14:26:09.504 BRT - Loaded bundle at path '/System/Library/OpenDirectory/Modules/FDESupport.bundle'
2012-08-06 14:26:09.525 BRT - Loaded bundle at path '/System/Library/OpenDirectory/Modules/ConfigurationProfiles.bundle'
2012-08-06 14:26:09.526 BRT - Registered subnode with name '/Local/Default'
2012-08-06 14:26:09.532 BRT - Loaded bundle at path '/System/Library/OpenDirectory/Modules/ldap.bundle'
2012-08-06 14:26:10.238 BRT - Loaded bundle at path '/System/Library/OpenDirectory/Modules/AppleODClient.bundle'
2012-08-06 14:30:40.625 BRT - Starting shutdown process...
2012-08-06 14:30:40.625 BRT - Deregistered with Kernel for identity service requests
```

#### system.log (final part)

see [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/GYY66BaP), too large to include here

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific? What have you tried already, are there any error messages, is there something interesting in /var/log/* related to the issue etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to Google for the answer to your question? It's pretty straightforward:

http://www.google.com/?q=how+to+bind+Macintosh+to+LDAP

Comment: Hi @Lurch99! I tried, but it still fails with the tutorials I found.

anyway, thanks!

Comment: Hi @patrix! how can I attach the logs here? 
The beginning of the file looks like this: 2012-08-06 14:26:07.780 BRT - opendirectoryd (build 172.10) launched...
2012-08-06 14:26:07.780 BRT - Logging level limit changed to 'error'
2012-08-06 14:26:07.788 BRT - Initialize trigger support
2012-08-06 14:26:07.789 BRT - Registered node with name '/Active Directory' as hidden
2012-08-06 14:26:07.790 BRT - Registered node with name '/Configure' as hidden
2012-08-06 14:26:07.790 BRT - Discovered configuration for node name '/Contacts' at path '/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations//C...

Comment: Upload it to pastebin.com and add a comment to the *question* with the link. Somebody with edit rights will then edit the question for you.

Comment: opendirectoryd.log.9
-------------
http://pastebin.com/xx1JrtwA

Comment: system.log (final part) ---------------- http://pastebin.com/GYY66BaP

Comment: Hi @patrix, anything new?
Tnx!

Comment: I'm no LDAP specialist. All I know is that without logs the issue will be impossible to analyze. Do you have access to the server-side logs as well?

Comment: Not @patrix ! Only client-side. sorry.
Thanks anyway... ;)